# ifelse arithmetic in R

Tags: r, if-statement, date-arithmetic

How does basic arithmetic work inside an ifelse statement in R? I'm trying to create a new column simply by adding a number to another column of values, if the condition is met.

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)

start_date <- as.Date("2021-11-1")
end_date <- as.Date("2022-10-31")

ym <- seq(as.yearmon(start_date), as.yearmon(end_date), 1/12)

df <- data.frame(start = pmax(start_date, as.Date(ym)),
           end = pmin(end_date, as.Date(ym, frac = 1)),
           month = month.name[cycle(ym)],
           year = as.integer(ym),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$month_num <- match(df$month, month.name)
```

My goal: If month is between May to December (5->12) add "+1" to variable year (making new column "water_year"). If month is between Jan. to April, leave year "number" as is in the new column.

```
df$water_year <- df %>% ifelse(month_num >=5, (year+1), year)
```

Result:

```
> print(df)
        start        end     month year month_num  water_year
1  2021-11-01 2021-11-30  November 2021        11  2022
2  2021-12-01 2021-12-31  December 2021        12  2022
3  2022-01-01 2022-01-31   January 2022         1  2022
4  2022-02-01 2022-02-28  February 2022         2  2022
5  2022-03-01 2022-03-31     March 2022         3  2022
6  2022-04-01 2022-04-30     April 2022         4  2022
7  2022-05-01 2022-05-31       May 2022         5  2023
8  2022-06-01 2022-06-30      June 2022         6  2023
9  2022-07-01 2022-07-31      July 2022         7  2023
10 2022-08-01 2022-08-31    August 2022         8  2023
11 2022-09-01 2022-09-30 September 2022         9  2023
12 2022-10-01 2022-10-31   October 2022        10  2023
```

Comment: Put your `ifelse` inside a `mutate`.  Something like `... %>% mutate(water_year = ifelse(month_num >=5, (year+1), year))`.

Comment: or: `df$water_year <- ifelse(df$month_num >=5, (df$year+1), df$year)`

Comment: you could even do: `df$water_year <- df$year + (df$month_num >= 5)`